# What are the downsides of unnecessarily requiring the whole module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I only need to require one module (out of 6), but doing so would make the module I'm requiring less readable. For example, instead of doing this:

```
const { requestKrakenOrderbook } = require('./krakenUtils');
const orderbook = requestKrakenOrderbook();
```

I'd like to do this:

```
const krakenUtils = require('./krakenUtils')
const orderbook = krakenUtils.requestOrderbook()
```

What are the downsides of requiring the whole module like this?

What about this?

```
const getKrakenOrderbook = require('./krakenUtils').getOrderbook
```

Comment: i'd assume none, considering the entire thing is ran and then kept anyway.

Comment: Do you mean that you find wrapping `requestKrakenOrderbook` with curly braces is less readable?

Comment: Even in the first example, you're still requiring the entire module. You're just explicitly not using it.

Comment: Fissure King, no I mean the file krakenUtils.js is less readable.

Comment: jhpratt, I thought I was just taking a piece of it. But not sure why I thought that. Thanks.

Comment: The obvious downside is that you're importing extraneous code into your app and inflating your bundle size, which is bad for performance. If you only need one function, there's no need to incur additional loading time and payload size by including the whole library.

Comment: @icey-t Not quite. The rest is discarded immediately, but it _is_ loaded at first.

Comment: @A.Lamansky I just added another option to the bottom of my question. What do you think of this idea?

Comment: @jhpratt  I just added another option to the bottom of my question. What do you think of this idea?

Comment: @icey-t Assuming the difference in names is a mistake. If you only want to import part of the module, you need to use ES-style imports, not CommonJS. That's literally the only way around it.

Comment: @jhpratt No, not a mistake. I'm trying to name the module "getOrderbook", but use it in another file as "getKrakenOrderbook".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no downsides. CommonJS modules are evaluated on `require`, entire module export is normally cached, so there's no significant difference in performance or memory footprint.

Depending on what module exports are, it may be useful or not to store the entire module to a variable and use it as a namespace:

```
const { get } = require('./foo');

// 200 lines below
let result = get(); // what in the world we've got?..
```

vs.

```
const foo = require('./foo');

// 200 lines below
let result = foo.get(); // ah, we've got foo
```